# How to save a model with custom attributes that are not in the database? - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a situation where I have set some custom attributes on a model. These attributes don't exist in the database. When using `->isDirty()` on the model I get the custom attributes that don't belong in the database.

Is there some clean way to remove these attrbiutes before saving the model?

```
$model = SomeModel::find(1);
$model->database_attribute = 'I exists in the database';
$model->custom_not_in_database_attribute = 'I don\'t exists in the database';
$model->save(); // remove dirty on save?!
```

I can of course just unset them `unset($model->custom_not_in_database_attribute)`, but I like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this?

Something like (not existing) `$model->saveOriginalOnly()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use getAttributes() and getOriginal() like this :

```
    $model=Model::findOrFail($id);
    $model->new='new';

    foreach ($model->getAttributes() as $key => $value) {
        if(!in_array($key, array_keys($model->getOriginal())))
            unset($model->$key);
    }

    dd($model);
```

Comment: I guess I'll go for something like this, but making it method on the custom base model. The thing is I need the unset properties still later on. So I have to temporarly save them first.

Comment: if you need to create attributes and delete it after, you can create "permanent" attribute in your model and use it without delete each time. For example in your User.php (model): public function getFullNameAttribute(){
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    } and in your view you can call $user->full_name ;) (first_name and last_name are real attributes)

Answer (score 9):

An easier way to do is just to add this property as a model's property like this:

```php
class Land extends Eloquent {

public $thisFieldWontBeSavedInDatabase;

//...

}
```

and it's done.

With this simple declaration, eloquent won't trigger the __set() method to add to the $attributes property. And only the fields in the $attributes property are saved in the database.

Answer (score 3):

The full solution for me was adding this method to the custom base model. It saves the original fields. But keeps the custom attributes.

```
public function saveOriginalOnly()
{
    $dirty = $this->getDirty();

    foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $key => $value) {
        if(!in_array($key, array_keys($this->getOriginal()))) unset($this->$key);
    }

    $isSaved = $this->save();
    foreach($dirty as $key => $value) {
        $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }

    return $isSaved;
}
```

See also: [Save a model with custom attributes - Laravel 5.4+](https://web.archive.org/web/20200920175247/https://codeneverlied.com/how-to-save-a-model-with-custom-attributes-that-are-not-in-the-database-laravel-5-4/)